# create html table in string format "<table> ..." based on string arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

> I am trying to create a table based on some input parameters "header,
> body" the header receives a string "header1, header" with its values
> separated by, and the body receives an array containing arrays with
> strings separated by, I try to paint the body values but the values
> are displayed horizontally.

***This post applies to an environment where you cannot manipulate the dom "Oracle Integration Cloud"***

```js
function convertStringToHtml(headers, body) {
  var headersArr = headers.split(",");
  var table = "<table>";
  var tableHeader = "<thead><tr>";
  var tableBody = "<tbody>";
  var bodyArr = [];

  headersArr.forEach((headerTable) => {
    tableHeader = tableHeader + "<th>" + headerTable + "</th>";
  });

  body.forEach((bodyTable) => {
    bodyTable.forEach((List) => {
      bodyArr.push(List.split(","));
    });
  });

  var longest = bodyArr.reduce(
    (headers, body) => (headers.length > body.length ? headers : body), []
  );

  bodyArr.forEach((bodyList, listKey) => {
    tableBody = tableBody + "<tr>";

    bodyList.forEach((list, key) => {
      console.log(list);
      if (list.length !== longest.length - 1) {
        console.log(" list: ", list, " key :", key, " listKey:", listKey);
        tableBody = tableBody + "<td>" + bodyArr[listKey][key] + "</td>";
      }
    });

    tableBody = tableBody + "</tr>";
  });

  table =
    "<table>" +
    tableHeader +
    "</tr></thead>" +
    tableBody +
    "</tbody>" +
    "</table>";
  return table;
}

var headerList = "Header 1,Header 2,Header 3";
var dataList = [
  ["TEST1,TEST1,TEST1"],
  ["TEST2,TEST2,TEST2"],
  ["TEST3,TEST3,TEST3"],
];

console.log(convertStringToHtml(headerList, dataList));
```

**Response Expected**

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>TEST1</td>
      <td>TEST2</td>
      <td>TEST3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TEST1</td>
      <td>TEST2</td>
      <td>TEST3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TEST1</td>
      <td>TEST2</td>
      <td>TEST3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't expect us to go to a codepen to see your code.  [mcve], make it on site.

Comment: ok i will modify the publication

Comment: If its already working what is the issue

Comment: It looks like a homework. Please show what you already did / tried.

Comment: You may be more comfortable asking this question and responding to comments over on [es.so]. Stack Overflow (this site) is English only.

Comment: It appears as though you want to "pivot" or "transpose" the data in `dataList` before rendering it. I suggest highlighting that in your question, showing the current outcome of your code and how it differs from your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Solution:

```
function convertStringToHtml(headers, body) {
      var headersArr = headers.split(",");
      var table = "<table>";
      var tableHeader = "<thead><tr>";
      var tableBody = "<tbody>";
      var bodyArr = [];
      // Order Array Data
      var orderArr = [];
      var responseArr = [];
      const lengthBodyElementArr = body[0][0].split(",").length;
    
      // Create Header Table
      headersArr.forEach((headerTable) => {
        tableHeader = tableHeader + "<th>" + headerTable + "</th>";
      });
    
      // Order Array
      for (var increment = 0; increment < lengthBodyElementArr; increment++) {
        orderArr = [];
        body.forEach((bodyElement) => {
          bodyElement.forEach((internalBodyElement) => {
            bodyArr = internalBodyElement.split(",");
            bodyArr.forEach((element, key) => {
              if (key == increment) {
                orderArr.push(element);
              }
            });
          });
        });
        responseArr.push(orderArr);
      }
    
      // Create Body Table
      responseArr.forEach((bodyList) => {
        tableBody = tableBody + "<tr>";
    
        bodyList.forEach((element) => {
          tableBody = tableBody + "<td>" + element + "</td>";
        });
    
        tableBody = tableBody + "</tr>";
      });
    
      table =
        "<table>" +
        tableHeader +
        "</tr></thead>" +
        tableBody +
        "</tbody>" +
        "</table>";
      return table;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Taplar said you should include a minimal reproducible example and follow the website's best practices.

That said, and generally speaking, once you have a string that contains some HTML you can insert in your page and to do that you need an DOM node.

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Once you have created your *container* or you have identified the one you want to put your element into, you can do so by selecting it and working with its `innerHTML` attribute.

```js
let rootElement = document.querySelector('#root')
document.innerHTML = "<table><thead><tr><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th><th>Header 3</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>TEST1</td><td>TEST1</td><td>TEST1</td></tr><tr><td>TEST2</td><td>TEST2</td><td>TEST2</td></tr><tr><td>TEST3</td><td>TEST3</td><td>TEST3</td></tr></tbody></table>"
```

You can find more info on this attribute [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Comment: I just updated the post sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: what you comment is correct to attach the html elements to the dom but in this case I have to apply them to a different environment oracle integration cloud where I cannot manipulate the dom

Comment: How were we supposed to know that if you didn't write in that in the original question? And what do you mean by "manipulate"? Do you mean you can't create new elements or that you cannot even interact with them? If the answer is the first then find an already existing element and append your table to it, if the answer is the second then there's not much you can do I guess.

Comment: you are right, I apologize for writing the post wrong. if it is an environment where I cannot modify or interact with the dom I can only create a string with the labels to be painted

Answer (score 0):

```js
var headerList = "Header 1,Header 2,Header 3";
var dataList = [
  ["TEST11,TEST12,TEST13"],
  ["TEST21,TEST22,TEST23"],
  ["TEST31,TEST32,TEST33"],
];

var tableHTML=
  "<table border=1>\n"+
    "  <thead>\n"+
      "    <tr>\n"+
        headerList.split(",").map(header=>"      <th>"+header+"</th>\n").join("")+
      "    </tr>\n"+
    "  </thead>\n"+
    "  <tbody>\n"+
      dataList.map(row=>"    <tr>\n"+
        row[0].split(",").map(cell=>"      <td>"+cell+"</td>\n").join("")+
      "    </tr>\n").join("")+
    "  </tbody>\n"+
  "</table>";

document.body.innerHTML+=tableHTML;
console.log(tableHTML);
```

`headerList.split(",")` returns an array of headers.
Then, we map each to be surrounded with `th`.
Then, we join them to be the content of the row.

`dataList.map` takes each sub array of the body - `dataList`.
`row[0]` takes the first (and only) item of those sub arrays.
We then `split` for each cell content and surround with `td`.
Then, we join them to be the content of a row.
It's done until all rows are created.

We surround the header row with `thead`, and
the body rows with `tbody`, and
the whole thing with `table`.

At the end, we add `tableHTML` to the `document.body`'s `innerHTML` -
and we're done!

Added indentation and linebreaks.

Comment: Stack Overflow encourages answers with explanation of code rather than just a dump of code. See [answer]: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."

Comment: @HereticMonkey, done.  May I get an up-vote, please?

Comment: If you look closely at the OP's expected output, the first row has "TEST 1", "TEST 2", "TEST 3". Your result has "TEST 1", "TEST 1", "TEST 1".

Comment: @HereticMonkey, Things you should take into account before commenting: OP edits. OP has edited the question, and the expected output does not reflect OP's own data. Anyways, I've edited my suggested solution to have row number then column number after the word "TEST".

Comment: I'm sure you can convert my code to a function.
By the way, your data doesn't match your expected output.
Seems you've used my snippet for expected output - would you select my answer?
Anything more you'd like?

Comment: Things you should take into account before talking down to others; the [edit history of the question is publicly available](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63820318/revisions), where one can see that the expected result and data remained the same.